# delete nodes from XML java

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have a huge XML file and I want to delete all elements except two in java. Example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <root>
      <c1></c1>
      <c1></c1>
      <c2></c2>
      <c3></c3>
      <c1></c1>
      .
      .
      .
      <cn></cn>
    </root>
</xml>
```

out put should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
    <root>
      <c1></c1>
      <c1></c1>
      <c2></c2>
      <c1></c1>
    </root>
```

Any help is much appreciated thnx.

Answer (score 1):

```
NodeList childeren = rootNode.getChildNodes();
```

remove relevant child nodes by iterating and removing desired node

```
  rootNode.removeChild(child)
```

And write back your changes to the file.

```
// write back to xml file

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Comment: ` for (int j = 0; j < nodeList.getLength(); j++) {
                   if(nodeList.item(j).getNodeName().equals("c1") || nodeList.item(j).getNodeName().equals("c2"))
                   {}else{
                       root.removeChild(nodeList.item(j));
                      
                   }
            }`                                                       Your last 5 lines are after for loop and this is not deleting any thing from document.